# ASP.Net MVC project doesn't start at the proper url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm an absolute beginner at asp.net mvc, i am not sure what changes i made to the project but now upon debugging the project in visual studio 2013, it starts at the path

> localhost:port/views/controller/action

instead of

> localhost:port/controller/action

and thus giving me a 404 not found error. How do i go about resolving this and rectifying this path? Upon changing this manually to /controller/action the page loads properly but somewhy on debugging it always tries to access the wrong path.

Comment: It's set to start at the currently opened page, which happens to be a view. Configure a startup URL instead.

Comment: UPDATE - was able to resolve it by setting specific page manually and running it on iis express for project url. Thanks!

It always redirects to /Views/Home/Index even if the currently opened page is /Auth/Login. This happens even when the page is not a view. RouteConfig.cs is fine, the home controller and index have been registered too, really dont know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your app while current open window in Visual Studio is your view page, try to switch to controller.

Comment: That didn't work. I really don't want to create a new project, this is bugging me a lot.